# How to create RESTful query language in Spring Data REST

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have Spring Data REST based web application which contains entities and repositories. When I want to filter based on entity fields I can use `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`. When precise equals is too much, I can use `QuerydslBinderCustomizer`, e.g.

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>,
        QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Person>,
        QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QPerson> {

    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QPerson personRoot) {

        bindings.bind(personRoot.name)
                .first(StringExpression::containsIgnoreCase);
    }           
}
```

Is there any way to build query language in Spring Data REST?

What I mean is to actually allow users to use various operations such as `>`, `<`, `<=`, `>=`, not only equals or its customization.

Comment: https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
@Query("select * from XXX")
public List<Object[]> findByUsername(String userName);
```